# Silverlight - Binding child ItemsControl source to a property in a parent ItemsControl source

Tags: c#, silverlight, data-binding, itemscontrol

I've got an ItemsControl that has another ItemsControl in it.
which means, for each item in the parent list, i want to show all the items in the child list.

so the Xaml is something like this (I'm neglecting some of the DataTemplate)"

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="dayPanel" Grid.Column="1">
       <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
                 <Grid>
                     <ItemsControl x:Name="dayHours" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource={Binding HourItems}">
                         <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                              <DataTemplate>
                              </DataTemplate>
                         </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                     </ItemsControl>
                 </Grid>
           </DataTemplate>
       </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Now in the Code behind i Make a Class that creates a list of days, and each day contains a list of hours.
so i get something like this:

```
public WeekPanel()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dayPanel.ItemsSource = new Dayx().CreateDays();
    }
```

So.. the first part, that i define in code, works fine.
but the child ItemsControl doesn't get populated.
I want to bind it to the property: HourItems
how do i do that?

**Edit:**
Okay, the problem was that HourItems property was defined as:

```
Public List<Hour> HourItem {get; set;}
```

but it worked when i changed it to:

```
public List<Hour> HourItems
        {
            get { return hourItems; }
            set { hourItems = value; }
        }
```

what's the difference that made it work?

Comment: The only difference as far as I can see is the spelling. Is that a typo?

Comment: Aside from a typo (`HourItem` vs. `HourItems`) the only difference is that one is an auto-property, while the other is a regular property with a backing (hopefully private) member.

Comment: So why did the auto property didn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="dayPanel" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource={Binding}>
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
             <Grid>
                 <ItemsControl x:Name="dayHours" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource={Binding HourItems}">
                     <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                          <DataTemplate>
                          </DataTemplate>
                     </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                 </ItemsControl>
             </Grid>
       </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

```
public WeekPanel()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    dayPanel.DataContext = new Dayx().CreateDays();
}
```

Try that code above. Basically I've set the datacontext of your itemscontrol object to your datasource, the ItemsSource then takes the value from itself and the DataContext should pass itself down.

Failing that, have a look in the output window while debugging because that usually tells you if something fails to bind.

Comment: the output window gave this error:
System.Windows.Data Error: Cannot get 'HourItems' value (type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Sisy.Hour]') from 'Sisy.Dayx' (type 'Sisy.Dayx'). BindingExpression: Path='HourItems' DataItem='Sisy.Dayx' (HashCode=52380055); target element is 'System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl' (Name='dayHours'); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable').. System.MethodAccessException: Attempt by method 'System.Windows.CLRPropertyListener.get_Value()' to access method 'Sisy.Dayx.get_HourItems()' failed.

Comment: oh jeez.. i found the answer... i'm gonna edit my post
thanks for reminding me about the output window.

Answer (score 0):

In your `ItemsControl`, try using a `RelativeSource`:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="dayHours" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=ItemsSource }">
```

Helpful links:

- MSDN [Binding.RelativeSource Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.relativesource%28VS.96%29.aspx)
- Silverlight forums [Using property value of parent UserControl](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/182892/418054.aspx)

Comment: I tried something like that (only difference is i gave Path="HourItems".
Doesn't work =/